# Issue while copying existing blob to Azure Media Services

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage, azure-media-services

We are trying to copy the existing blob to AMS but it is not getting copied. Blob resides in storage account 1 and AMS is associated with storage account 2. All the accounts including AMS are in the same location.

```
   await destinationBlob.StartCopyAsync(new Uri(sourceBlob.Uri.AbsoluteUri + signature));
```

When visualizing the AMS Storage Account using Blob Storage explorer, asset folders are getting created but with no blobs in it. Also, within the Media explorer, we can see the assets listed in the AMS but when clicked, not found exception is thrown. Basically they are not getting fully copied into the AMS.

However, when we use same code and attach a new  AMS to the blob storage account (storage account1) where the actual blob resides, copy is working fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have not reproduce your issue. But there is a [code sample](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/samples/media-services-dotnet-copy-blob-into-asset/) to copy existing blob to Azure media services via .NET SDK. Please try to copy the Blob using `StartCopyFromBlob` or `StartCopyFromBlobAsync`(the Azure storage client library 4.3.0). Below is the code snippet in the code sample :

```html
                destinationBlob.StartCopyFromBlob(new Uri(sourceBlob.Uri.AbsoluteUri + signature));

                while (true)
                {
                    // The StartCopyFromBlob is an async operation, 
                    // so we want to check if the copy operation is completed before proceeding. 
                    // To do that, we call FetchAttributes on the blob and check the CopyStatus. 
                    destinationBlob.FetchAttributes();
                    if (destinationBlob.CopyState.Status != CopyStatus.Pending)
                    {
                        break;
                    }
                    //It's still not completed. So wait for some time.
                    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
                }
```

Comment: We are using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.dll v7.2.1.0 and the dll in your reference project is  v4.3.0.0.  So, not able to find StartCopyFromBlob()?

Comment: Sorry for my mistake, I will try to use the latest storage library to reproduce your issue.

Comment: I write a sample code base on above sample code with the latest version of storage library. Everything works fine. If you failed to copy the blob. Is there any problem with the file stored in Azure destination Blob?

Comment: File is not getting copied and no exception is thrown after the while loop is completed. We can view the asset visually with the actual size but when we click on it, it is actually empty.

Comment: If I create a new AMS account and point to Storage account where the blob exits, copy works just fine. I can see the asset container getting created in the root.

Comment: Blob not found (http) exception is getting thrown when i try to download the asset.

Comment: My mistake, the destination storage account was always pointing to the storage account 1. So, it is not able to create an asset in ams storage account. Thank you.